# Python namespace 'import X' and 'from X import'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, namespaces

The following code works:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

However, the following:

```
import sqlalchemy
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
```

throws: `module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'ext'`. How can that be?

Answer (score 4):

`sqlalchemy` is a package, and importing a package doesn't automatically load its submodules. When you do

```
import sqlalchemy
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
```

The import system doesn't load the `sqlalchemy.ext` submodule, because you didn't ask for it.

When you do

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

You've explicitly requested that `sqlalchemy.ext` and `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative` get loaded, so the access works.

You also could have done

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
```

which would also load `sqlalchemy.ext` and `sqlalchemy.ext.declarative`.

Some packages automatically load their submodules inside their `__init__.py`, so you don't have to import submodules explicitly. This isn't something you should rely on, though.